# (Tizen studio, wearable, web app) How to detect long press on back-hardware button?

Tags: tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

I'm developing a web app for Samsung wearable device and I would like to detect when user makes a long press on a back-hardware button.

The only information that I have found so far is this:

```
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {...});
```

The problem? This event fires only when back-button is released, but unfortunately it doesn't fire when the back-button is pressed - and for detecting long press when need information when back-button is pressed and when it was released.

Any ideas how to detect a long press of back-hardware button?

Answer (score 1):

There indeed is no way to detect a long press with Tizen Web. An alternative could be to detect a quick double-press, instead of a long press. That can be accomplished using timers.

E.g.

```js
const doubleClickWaitTime = 400;
let doubleClickTimeout = -1;

window.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyName === 'back') {
      if (doubleClickTimeout === -1) {
        // First click of back button
        doubleClickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          doubleClickTimeout = -1;
          backButtonSinglePress();
        }, doubleClickWaitTime);
      } else {
        // Second click of back button
        clearTimeout(doubleClickTimeout);
        doubleClickTimeout = -1;
        backButtonDoublePress();
      }
    }
});

function backButtonSinglePress() {
  // Single press
}

function backButtonDoublePress() {
  // Double press
}
```

This does the following:

- When the user clicks the hardware key, a timer is started that fires a function after `doubleClickWaitTime` milliseconds.
- If the user presses the hardware button again during this time, the timer is canceled, and `backButtonDoublePress()` is called.
- If the user doesn't press the hardware button again, the timer fires and executes `backButtonSinglePress()` after resetting the timer.

The `doubleClickWaitTime` variable can be modified to give the user more time for a double click. However, the longer this delay, the longer a single click event takes to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the docuement.
But Tizen platform does not provide a way to distinguish between press and release of hardware key.

https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/tau/event-handling/